# Passing variables to the sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed, variable

We have a file containing 6 columns:

```
FILEDESCRIPTOR . DESCR00001     FILEDESCRIPTOR  .  DESCRIPTIVENAME
FILEDESCRIPTOR . LSTUPDNAM      FILEDESCRIPTOR  .  LASTUPDATENAME
FILEDESCRIPTOR . LOCAT00001     FILEDESCRIPTOR  .  LOCATION_ID
FILEDESCRIPTOR . RETAILPRC      FILEDESCRIPTOR  .  RETAILPRICE
FILEDESCRIPTOR . LSTUPDTIME     FILEDESCRIPTOR  .  UPDTIMESTAMP
INDUSTRYDIVISION . DESCR00001   INDUSTRYDIVISION  .  DESCRIPTION
INDUSTRYDIVISION . DIVIS00001   INDUSTRYDIVISION  .  DIVISIONCODE
INDUSTRYGROUP . DESCR00001      INDUSTRYGROUP  .  DESCRIPTION
INDUSTRYGROUP . DIVIS00001      INDUSTRYGROUP  .  DIVISION_ID
```

All I need to do is treat the first 3 columns separated by a single space and store it in a variable as a single column, and then store the next three that are separated by a single space into another variable. Then, use `sed` to replace the first variable with the second.

I tried the below script but threw errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
        column2="$(echo -e "$line \n" | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')"
        #column3="$(echo -e "$line \n" | awk '{print $3}')"
        column1="$(echo -e "$line \n" | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' )"
        #echo " $column1"
        #echo " $column2"
                 sed  "s/${column1}/${column2}/g" IMS_Procedures.txt
done < file
```

The script is not working. The errors I got are:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command
```

What can be done?

Comment: That doesn't really matter. That is just a file, and this command prints it with single space      `column2="$(echo -e "$line \n" | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')"`   When you `echo $column2` it is printing with single space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$column1` and `$column2` variable there is a newline at the end and the `sed` command looks then like this:

```
sed  "s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . DESCR00001
  /FILEDESCRIPTOR . DESCRIPTIVENAME
  /g" IMS_Procedures.txt
```

`sed` recognizes this as an unterminated s command.

---

Use this instead:

```
while read -r a b c d e f; do
  sed -i "s/$a $b $c/$d $e $f/g" IMS_Procedures.txt
done <file
```

- `read` store the 6 fields in the variables `$a` to `$f`

  - Then `sed` replaces the first 3 fields as a space separated stringwith the last 3 in the file `IMS_Procedures.txt`. `-i` activates in-place editing, that the changes are written to the file, instead of printed to the screen.

Notice the `.` in `sed` will match any character not only the dot. That has to be esacped with `\.` in the input `file`.

Comment: hey @chaos this one i have tried earlier and worked.but the just wondering y the other one dint work though.

Comment: can u pls tell me how to sort that out. `"sed recognizes this as an unterminated s command". pls just curious"`

Comment: @VishalArukil change `column2="$(echo -e "$line \n" | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')"` to `column2="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')"` (without the `\n`)

Answer (score 3):

No need to `while read`...
You could simply process your input file:

```
sed 's|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}|/|3;s|.*|s/&/g|' infile
```

and turn it into a `sed` script:

```
s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . DESCR00001/FILEDESCRIPTOR . DESCRIPTIVENAME/g
s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . LSTUPDNAM/FILEDESCRIPTOR . LASTUPDATENAME/g
s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . LOCAT00001/FILEDESCRIPTOR . LOCATION_ID/g
s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . RETAILPRC/FILEDESCRIPTOR . RETAILPRICE/g
s/FILEDESCRIPTOR . LSTUPDTIME/FILEDESCRIPTOR . UPDTIMESTAMP/g
s/INDUSTRYDIVISION . DESCR00001/INDUSTRYDIVISION . DESCRIPTION/g
s/INDUSTRYDIVISION . DIVIS00001/INDUSTRYDIVISION . DIVISIONCODE/g
s/INDUSTRYGROUP . DESCR00001/INDUSTRYGROUP . DESCRIPTION/g
s/INDUSTRYGROUP . DIVIS00001/INDUSTRYGROUP . DIVISION_ID/g
```

and pipe that to a second `sed -f-` to process your IMS_`Procedures.txt`:

```
sed 's|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}|/|3;s|.*|s/&/g|' infile | sed -f- IMS_Procedures.txt
```

I don't quite understand what "this is a file and this command prints it with single space" means so if fields in your `infile` are delimited by more than one space then you could use `tr` first:

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]]' ' ' <infile | sed 's| |/|3;s|.*|s/&/g|' | sed -f- IMS_Procedures.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the obvious :

```
awk '{printf "s/%s%s%s/%s%s%s/\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6} ' file |
sed -i -f - IMS_Procedures.txt
```

where sed file is generate by awk.

you can adjust space using

```
awk '{printf "s/%s %s %s/%s %s %s/\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
```